# Can't access main camera (stuck in wide angle)

Tags: camera

My Zenfone 4 Max camera app is stuck on the wide angle camera. The icon on the picture below says it's the main camera, but it's possible to see by the curve on my wall that it's indeed in wide angle. When I click on the wide angle icon, system says it's now on wide angle, but the image doesn't change.

I have tried restarting in safe mode, clearing app's cache, restarting normally and tried using 3rd party camera apps. No success so far.

Any way to fix this without having to take it to Asus tech support (they take forever to answer) and/or restoring factory settings?

[image]

Comment: So far the only fixed I could find was to reset to factory Settings. Nothing else worked (rebooting, clearing camera cache, installing a 3rd party camera app, etc)